# How to create a table from a json api using HTML tables

Tags: html, ajax, html-table

We are using an api to retrieve data from MySQL database and turning it into a json file type. What would be the best way to get that data into an HTML table.

This is the api: https://nauticmc.com/dev/top.php?type=kills&start=0&end=9

Depending on what you change the type to it will change ascending order of the data I.E Kills will display the heights amount of kills first.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = [{"uuid":"ba6df9ff-84fa-464b-a231-d36782a7fdba","username":"zFrost87","kills":"19","deaths":"6","broken":"34","placed":"34","fish":"15","onlinetime":"9493","mobskilled":"6","crops":"1"},{"uuid":"b07762f3-38a4-45b7-9f21-6147704aee4b","username":"frechette456","kills":"3","deaths":"11","broken":"33","placed":"61","fish":"0","onlinetime":"1251","mobskilled":"1","crops":"7"},{"uuid":"83af0a86-7c09-4c32-8fa5-65db3c50b4cf","username":"MineManFrost","kills":"1","deaths":"2","broken":"16","placed":"1","fish":"0","onlinetime":"238","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"71cb5612-d586-4390-ad78-05d295d6d2bd","username":"Nikolassparrow","kills":"0","deaths":"2","broken":"1","placed":"2","fish":"0","onlinetime":"30","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"c34f51b5-8f2a-4e08-8b83-99d5faf21ea9","username":"SetupS1CK","kills":"0","deaths":"0","broken":"0","placed":"0","fish":"0","onlinetime":"81","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"80212863-9466-4a4b-852e-5812e77d075b","username":"PickCottonNig","kills":"0","deaths":"0","broken":"0","placed":"0","fish":"0","onlinetime":"835","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"a64de20f-91e7-4bb0-80db-4f7f1614d693","username":"OstenGaming","kills":"0","deaths":"0","broken":"1","placed":"0","fish":"0","onlinetime":"213","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"25c60209-9fd4-42b8-a2b7-d78e01c0b3ae","username":"OpTc","kills":"0","deaths":"0","broken":"0","placed":"0","fish":"0","onlinetime":"9","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"3a1dc4c7-e9ec-425e-ad50-54ae37c5f1a7","username":"AutoDolphin","kills":"0","deaths":"11","broken":"20","placed":"1","fish":"0","onlinetime":"444","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"}];
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].username + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].kills + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].deaths + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].broken + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].placed + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].fish + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].onlinetime + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].mobskilled + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].crops + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
});
```

I am using Local JSON for now because Ajax does not allow access cross domain but I would parse it into a var to get it.

I also want people to be able to see what data is on top by corresponding arrows in each column I tried to use datatables.js but that did not work so well

This is just the table without any js or json

https://strixdesigns.com/Stats1/ < I want the arrows to work like this

Comment: Your above code already inserts the JSON data into the table. What exactly are you struggling with - retrieving it from the server with AJAX?

Comment: When I look at my JS console on your example page, I'm seeing a mixed content error. This could be causing the problem. You need to load jQuery from a secure (https) location. Grab a url from [here](https://code.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont use datatable and set the options like this
your thead field must the same on your json field count

## HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Kills</th>
            ....
        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "https://nauticmc.com/dev/top.php?type=kills&start=0&end=9",
           "type": "POST",
           "data":{
                     'type': 'kills',
                     'start': 0,
                     'end': 9
                 }
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "username " },
            { "data": "kills " },
            ...
        ]
    } );
} );
```

check documentation here: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html

Comment: @ThatPurpleGuy Please kindly up if this helped you.

Comment: Im pretty sure that i cant get json file from that site because it is just stuck on loading https://gyazo.com/51d9d3cff1ee42f9a4752778c8f17a71

Comment: @ThatPurpleGuy if type = "post" not working try type="get"

Comment: So here is what i got for an error
DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
https://nauticmc.com/stats/

Comment: @ThatPurpleGuy please check your php is not returning json data

Comment: maybe if we could try it with just plain json without using a url

Comment: Figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to store the desired order in an array and add a nested loop to your logic. The advantage here is that you can change the order to whatever you'd like (`username` last, third, etc.) and your markup will not have to change to accommodate the reordering of fields.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = [{"uuid":"ba6df9ff-84fa-464b-a231-d36782a7fdba","username":"zFrost87","kills":"19","deaths":"6","broken":"34","placed":"34","fish":"15","onlinetime":"9493","mobskilled":"6","crops":"1"},{"uuid":"b07762f3-38a4-45b7-9f21-6147704aee4b","username":"frechette456","kills":"3","deaths":"11","broken":"33","placed":"61","fish":"0","onlinetime":"1251","mobskilled":"1","crops":"7"},{"uuid":"83af0a86-7c09-4c32-8fa5-65db3c50b4cf","username":"MineManFrost","kills":"1","deaths":"2","broken":"16","placed":"1","fish":"0","onlinetime":"238","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"71cb5612-d586-4390-ad78-05d295d6d2bd","username":"Nikolassparrow","kills":"0","deaths":"2","broken":"1","placed":"2","fish":"0","onlinetime":"30","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"c34f51b5-8f2a-4e08-8b83-99d5faf21ea9","username":"SetupS1CK","kills":"0","deaths":"0","broken":"0","placed":"0","fish":"0","onlinetime":"81","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"80212863-9466-4a4b-852e-5812e77d075b","username":"PickCottonNig","kills":"0","deaths":"0","broken":"0","placed":"0","fish":"0","onlinetime":"835","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"a64de20f-91e7-4bb0-80db-4f7f1614d693","username":"OstenGaming","kills":"0","deaths":"0","broken":"1","placed":"0","fish":"0","onlinetime":"213","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"25c60209-9fd4-42b8-a2b7-d78e01c0b3ae","username":"OpTc","kills":"0","deaths":"0","broken":"0","placed":"0","fish":"0","onlinetime":"9","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"},{"uuid":"3a1dc4c7-e9ec-425e-ad50-54ae37c5f1a7","username":"AutoDolphin","kills":"0","deaths":"11","broken":"20","placed":"1","fish":"0","onlinetime":"444","mobskilled":"0","crops":"0"}];
    var tr, th;
    var order = ['username', 'kills', 'deaths', 'broken', 'placed', 'fish', 'onlinetime', 'mobskilled', 'crops'];
  
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      tr = $('<tr/>');
      th = $('<tr/>');
      
      if (i === 0) { // create table headers               
        for (var j = 0; j < order.length; j++) { 
          th.append("<th>" + order[j] + "</th>");
          $('table').append(th)
        }         
      }     
      
      for (var j = 0; j < order.length; j++) { 
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i][order[j]] + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);      
      }
    }
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#666;
  font-size:12px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
  background:#eaebec;
  margin:20px;
  border:#ccc 1px solid;
  border-radius:3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

table th {
  padding:21px 25px 22px 25px;
  border-top:1px solid #fafafa;
  border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background: #ededed;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#ebebeb));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed,  #ebebeb);
}
table th:first-child {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left:20px;
}
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius:3px;
}
table tr:first-child th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius:3px;
}
table tr {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left:20px;
}
table td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left:20px;
  border-left: 0;
}
table td {
  padding:18px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;

  background: #fafafa;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb,  #fafafa);
}
table tr.even td {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8f8f8), to(#f6f6f6));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f8f8f8,  #f6f6f6);
}
table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom:0;
}
table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}
table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}
table tr:hover td {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f2f2f2), to(#f0f0f0));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f2f2,  #f0f0f0);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Comment: This works but i am not using Datatables js so there is not a way for me to sort the data more easily

Comment: @ThatPurpleGuy ?

Comment: I added table headers to my example, because why not?